# How to add mavlink library in a Qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, qgroundcontrol

I am making a Qt project based on `QGroundControl` which uses mavlink library. I googled it but not able to find the correct way. It can not be added as other libraries as it is a header only library. Please someone tell me the correct way to do it.

Comment: _'it is a header only library'_ Just include the headers then??

Comment: Was not that enough described here -- https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol#build-on-linux (for building for Linux)? Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, this is not just a header-only library, so you will need to link against it either through direct `LIBS` usage or pkg-config if you get such a thing. In the former case, you may also need to adjust the `INCLUDEPATH` variable.

Then, in the source code you just do the regular include:

```
 #include <mavlink.h>
```

But that is probably not what you want, I think. You want to deal with QGroundControl in your project as that is your direct dependency. They do not seem to ship a `.prf` file though, so `CONFIG+=x` will not work.

However, if you install it properly, you may not even need to adjust the `LIBS` and `INCLUDEPATH` variables. In worst case, you have to. I think that is pretty much about it. You could also use pkg-config to deal with it as they seem to ship a `.pc` file.

Comment: corrected myself. I just have to give the header file path in includepath in .pro file btw thanks for answering